# Send SMS from a PC using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, sms

hai how to send sms with sender name instead of phone number using the AT Command sets in vb.net 2005.
  is this is possible give idea to me.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Most AT commands for mobile phones are specified in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm), however the SMS related commands are specified in [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm). I do not remember if the sms command supports name as input, but you should be able to use AT+CPBF to look up the number at least as a two step solution.